# How can I fetch data from html page to json page in android?

Tags: android, html, json, fetch

I have one html file called temp.html and its contents are like,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hello
</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3 style="color:red;"> 1. How are you </h3>
<h4> &nbsp;&nbsp; &rtrif; I am fine.. </h4>

...........................

 <body>
<h3 style="color:red;"> 100. Who are you? </h3>
<h4> &nbsp;&nbsp; &rtrif; I am Jack Smith.. </h4>

</body>
</html>
```

So, now I want to have these 100+ question directly fetched to the json file, in temp.json file like,

```
[
     {
        "q":"1. How are you",
        "a":" I am fine.."
     },

...............................

     {
        "q":"100. Who are you?",
        "a":"I am Jack Smith.."
     }
]
```

So, this way I want to have json file.. I can create json file manually, but whenever I update my html file, I have to update the json file, and for 100+ questions, it is sometimes hard to manage..

So, tell me how can I fetch / convert json file from html page..

Comment: use jsoup html parser to parse the tags and fetch the contents and then create a json.

Comment: I will try and will let you know..